# Porting old apps from Python 2.4

Tags: python, performance

I have a bunch of apps written in Python 2.4. I'd like to port them onto more recent version of the interpreter. Let's say I have no need of syntax features, but I am very concerned about performance. So which of the upper python versions is the fastest (the most optimized) - 2.4 or 2.5 or 2.6 or 2.7 ?

Performance comparison articles (URL) are much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In general, each successive version along the `2.*` line becomes a bit faster than the previous one -- because optimization and fine-tuning is a high priority for many contributors.

I don't know of any articles on performance configuration: my advice is to identify the "hot spots" of *your* specific application by profiling (but surely you're already doing that, if you are "very concerned about performance") and turn them into microbenchmarks to run on `timeit` across all four versions.

For example, suppose that `''.join`ing middling-length lists of shortish strings is known to be a hotspot in your applications.  Then, we could measure:

```
$ python2.4 -mtimeit -s'x=[str(i) for i in range(99)]' '"".join(x)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.87 usec per loop
$ python2.5 -mtimeit -s'x=[str(i) for i in range(99)]' '"".join(x)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.02 usec per loop
$ python2.6 -mtimeit -s'x=[str(i) for i in range(99)]' '"".join(x)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.7 usec per loop
$ python2.7 -mtimeit -s'x=[str(i) for i in range(99)]' '"".join(x)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.12 usec per loop
```

python2.5 in this case does not follow the other releases' general trend (repeating the measurement confirms it's about 5% slower than python2.4 on this microbenchmark) and 2.7 is surprisingly faster than expected (a whopping 26%+ faster than 2.4), but that's for a specific build and platform (as well of course as a specific microbenchmark), which is why it's important for *you* to perform such measurements on benchmarks and platforms/builds of *your* specific interest (if you're willing to just accept the general consideration that later builds tend to be faster, then you're not really "very" concerned about performance;-).

Comment: Testing on each one involves updating / rebuilding C++ extensions written using Boost Python, which is very time consuming...

Comment: if you can't isolate micro-benchmarks that matter to you without them involving the extensions, it must mean that the extensions are taking basically all the time (otherwise you could isolate and measure the performance-relevant parts where the extensions are **not** the bottlenecks), and therefore that worrying about the performance of Python proper is a totally misplaced idea.